# Do I need 'override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {}' in my project?

Tags: swift, macos

I got an error here: `override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {`

**The error:** Method does not override any of its superclass.

**The question:** Does the code `override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()` have to be in my project?

Comment: Are you sure you are editing a view controller subclass?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you don't. Delete it until you have a need for it.

Shocking, I know, because it's recommended and it's in the template. But in all my years of iOS development, I've only actually had something useful to put in there maybe four or five times (and most of those were back in the iPhone 3GS days when memory was more limited). Frankly, for new developers, I'd just leave it out until you're ready to worry about optimizing resource utilization at that level. I think it creates more confusion than it solves. You definitely shouldn't put it in there unless you also perform tests to make sure your memory warning code works.

As Alessandro notes, this method is only applicable for `UIViewController` subclasses. (For other types, you can observe `UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification`.) But you shouldn't just leave it in there because it's part of the template or because someone told you you should have it. If you don't have any meaningful memory to release (and honestly, view controllers seldom should), then you should get rid of the override.

Comment: Actually the question is tagged [osx].

Comment: @Sarcasm, heh. This doesn't even exist in OS X, so yeah, you'd want to delete it…

Answer (score 1):

[Apple developer library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/didReceiveMemoryWarning) says it:

> Sent to the view controller when the app receives a memory warning.
>
> Your app never calls this method directly. Instead, this method is
>   called when the system determines that the amount of available memory
>   is low.
>
> You can override this method to release any additional memory used by
>   your view controller. If you do, your implementation of this method
>   must call the super implementation at some point.

Probably you try to set this method in a class type different by a [view controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/).

This is **correct**:

```
class MyClass: UIViewController {    
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

This is an **error**:

```
class MySwitch: UIControl {
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't *need* to have `didReceiveMemoryWarning()`, but you *should*.

You're getting an error here because you're using the `override` keyword.

The `override` keyword states "this method overrides the method with the same name (`didReceiveMemoryWarning()`) in the superclass."

But if the superclass doesn't have `didReceiveMemoryWarning()`, then you're not overriding it, but you say you are. That's an error.

Either remove the method all together, or make your class a subclass of a class that implements that method.